# Add one more value to a select drop down menu in js

Tags: jquery, select, intervals

I wanna add the value 0" to the selectable dropdown.

```
var selectIntervalH = document.createElement('select');
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                switch(i) {
                    case 0:
                        break;
            option.value = '1/8';
            option.text = '1/8"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                    case 1:
            option.value = '1/4';
            option.text = '1/4"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 2:
            option.value = '3/8';
            option.text = '3/8"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 3:
            option.value = '1/2';
            option.text = '1/2"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 4:
            option.value = '5/8';
            option.text = '5/8"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 5:
            option.value = '3/4';
            option.text = '3/4"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 6:
            option.value = '7/8';
            option.text = '7/8"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

I wanna add the value 0" to the drop-down. I tought it was easy so I did this modification with no result. I see that an element is created (the selector) and that the variable is `i`:

```
var selectIntervalH = document.createElement('select');
            for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                switch(i) {
                    case 0:
                        break;
            option.value = '0';
            option.text = '0"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                    case 1:
                        break;
            option.value = '1/8';
            option.text = '1/8"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                    case 2:
            option.value = '1/4';
            option.text = '1/4"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 3:
            option.value = '3/8';
            option.text = '3/8"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 4:
            option.value = '1/2';
            option.text = '1/2"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 5:
            option.value = '5/8';
            option.text = '5/8"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 6:
            option.value = '3/4';
            option.text = '3/4"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                    case 7:
            option.value = '7/8';
            option.text = '7/8"';
            selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: SO is not a free tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

on `case 0:` `break` placed at the wrong place.

```
    case 0: 
        option.value = '1/8';
        option.text = '1/8"';
        selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);

         break; //<------ move it here
   case 1:
```

**Update:**

`case 1` `break` is also misplaced. correct that.

```
     case 1:
        option.value = '1/8';
        option.text = '1/8"';
        selectIntervalH.appendChild(option);

        break; //<------ move it here
```

Comment: How do I add a 8th value to the dropdown?

Comment: The valus as to be 0". I try to add another case (case 0 to case 7) but the 8th value doesnt show?

Comment: 'var selectIntervalH = document.createElement('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   var option = document.createElement('option');'

Comment: that's because `case 1` `break` is also misplaced. correct that.